# $3y''+4y'+y = 200 \cos x$ finding particular integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$3x''+4x'+x=200 \cos(t) $$
This is what I did:
\begin{align}
x &= \lambda \cos (t) + \mu \sin(t) \\
x' &= -\lambda \sin(t) + \mu \cos(t) \\ 
x''&= -\lambda \cos(t) - \mu \sin(t)
\end{align}
Substitute in to get: 
$$3\bigl( -\lambda \cos(t) - \mu \sin(t) \bigr) + 4\bigl(-\lambda \sin(t) + \mu \cos(t) \bigr) + \bigl(\lambda \cos(t) + \mu \sin(t) \bigr) =200 \cos(t) \\    
2\lambda \cos(t) + 2\mu \sin(t) = 200 \cos(t) $$
Can someone show their working as to how to get the correct answer, which is :
$40 \sin(t) - 20 \cos(t) $

Comment: Why don't you show how you got that answer? It could be that you got off to a good start, and simply made a mistake along the way. Alternatively, it could be that you just didn't start out quite right. Knowing which will help us provide you with a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got off to a good start, but didn't gather like terms correctly.

\begin{eqnarray}3x''+4x'+x &=& 3(-\lambda\cos t-\mu\sin t)+4(-\lambda\sin t+\mu\cos t)+\lambda\cos t+\mu\sin t\\ &=& -3\lambda\cos t-3\mu\sin t-4\lambda\sin t+4\mu\cos t+\lambda\cos t+\mu\sin t\\ &=& -3\lambda\cos t+4\mu\cos t+\lambda\cos t-3\mu\sin t-4\lambda\sin t+\mu\sin t\\ &=& (4\mu-2\lambda)\cos t-(2\mu+4\lambda)\sin t\end{eqnarray}

Since we need this to be equal to $200\cos t,$ then we must have $$2\mu+4\lambda=0$$ and $$4\mu-2\lambda=200.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: thanks, little errors can be very annoying to find :)

Comment: You're welcome! I typically find that it helps to show all of my steps, personally.